# How does the size of my sampling grid affect my required sample size

Tags: categorical-data, sampling, sample-size, spatial

I would like to know how sample size estimation is affected when the categories are artificial rather than naturally occurring and clearly discrete.

In my scenario I'm using a grid of a certain size (say 1 x 1m) to characterise land cover proportions. Let's say there are two possible categories of land cover A and B and I assign the category based on the amount of grass in the grid (>50% = A, < 50% = B).

I want to know how many samples I need to characterise the population proportion of land cover which may consist of a huge area where I could take many 1 x 1m samples.

If I follow the methods of a Gallup Poll it looks like I'd need to sample around 1000 1 x 1m grids to get a reasonable estimate of the population proportion.

But what happens if I increase or decrease the size of my sampling grid to 2 x 2m or 0.5 x 0.5m? This should decrease and increase the required sample size required but in what way? I'm confused because the category is an artificial one.

Comment: as you increase sampling grid you will need less samples (imagine if you take the grid to the max and you were able to sample the entire land mass, then you would only need sample size = 1. As the sampling grid gets smaller you will need more of them.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but how would this effect the statistics of sample size estimation? If I need a sample size of 1,000 for a population of a million do I need a sample size of 500 for a population of 500,000. I don't think it will be that simple especially in the case where the categories aren't natural.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on the specifics on how to analyze this, just wanted to give a quick sense of intuition.

Comment: Absolutely, and it was helpful to consider the limiting case where the gird is the size of the land mass.